# Ingress returning 404 with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to setup ingress to work with a kubernetes cluster as seen here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgVjEo3OGBI. When testing the endpoint in postman it is returning a 404 not found. I've tried using https and http and i'm at a loss. Thanks!

Edit: I was using a localhost for testing and am now trying to use acme.com as the routing url.

Ingress file:

```
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: acme.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/platforms
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: platforms-clusterip-service
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /api/c/platforms
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: commands-clusterip-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

---

Depl files

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: platforms-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: platformservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: platformservice
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: platformservice
          image: revlisc/platformservice:latest
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: platforms-clusterip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: platformservice
  ports:
  - name: platformservice
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: commands-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: commandservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: commandservice
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: commandservice
          image: revlisc/commandservice:latest

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: commands-clusterip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: commandservice
  ports:
  - name: commandservice
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

---

Service

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: platformnpservice-srv
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: platformservice
  ports:
    - name: platformservice
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Comment: post your deployment yaml and the url you are calling would help people to answer you

Comment: I posted the depl files and the url!

Comment: we will also need to see your service file and also have u installed ingress controller ?

Comment: service file: 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: platformnpservice-srv
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: platformservice
  ports:
    - name: platformservice
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80

Comment: Yup I installed ingress with kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.3.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml

Comment: update the service file in your question. you can edit and then update the svc file there. Also is the ingress controller running ?

Comment: Yes it is running

Comment: Also you have many mismatch in names as far as i know you misconfigured the labels

Comment: Does this work fine with other type of service ? Is this the expected output for /api/platforms ? `[{"id":1,"name":"Dot Net","publisher":"Microsoft","cost":"Free"},{"id":2,"name":"SQL Server Express","publisher":"Microsoft","cost":"Free"},{"id":3,"name":"Kubernetes","publisher":"Cloud Native Computing Foundation","cost":"Free"}]`

Comment: Yes it works when I use a node port or on localhost, the issue is with nginx. What do you mean the labels are misconfigured?

Comment: can u check my answer and test if that works? You might need to delete the existing deployment and then apply the new one. Also there was an issue with your ingress.yml file as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there was a change in ingress.yml which I have made and it works for me can you test using the below manifest and check if its working ?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: platforms-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: platformservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: platformservice
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: platformservice
          image: revlisc/platformservice:latest
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: platforms-clusterip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: platformservice
  ports:
  - name: platformservice
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

Also there was an issue with your ingress file as well i have made a small change. Check if this works for you

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: <your-hostname>
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/api/platforms"
        backend:
          service:
            name: platforms-clusterip-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

When I hit hostname/api/platforms I was able to see this output I am not sure if this is the expected result. Can you confirm ?

`[{"id":1,"name":"Dot Net","publisher":"Microsoft","cost":"Free"},{"id":2,"name":"SQL Server Express","publisher":"Microsoft","cost":"Free"},{"id":3,"name":"Kubernetes","publisher":"Cloud Native Computing Foundation","cost":"Free"}]`

Comment: `spec.selector.app` dosen't have to be Deployment name.

Comment: Oh then how does the service understand which deployment this is for ?

Comment: plz check the [selector and label](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/), selector is selecting the label instead of name

Comment: thanks for pointing out my mistake. edited the answer

Comment: I had to take out the rewrite-target but I am getting back the expected result!